# Unexpected increase in List.Count after adding elements to the list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

After running the following loop (one iteration), `battleshipParts.Count` returns 2.

The code is ran once in the `ScriptableObject.Awake`

```cs
for (byte i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    var battleshipPart = CreateInstance<BattleshipPart>();
    battleshipPart.battleshipData = this;
    battleshipParts.Add(battleshipPart);
}
```

I tried using the debugger and walking through the code, after the execution of

```cs
battleshipPart.battleshipData = this;
```

`battleshipParts.Count` is already 1

`battleshipPart.battleshipData` is used to hold a reference to its battleship parent. Implementation:

```cs
public class BattleshipPart : ScriptableObject
{
    public Vector2 gridPosition;
    public BattleshipData battleshipData;
    public bool isHit = false;
}
```

The `battleshipParts` list isn't modified anywhere else besides this code. Besides. Why would it update itself with a `null` value after running `battleshipPart.battleshipData = this;`?

Comment: Where is `battleshipParts` declared and initialized? Where else is it used in any code anywhere?

Comment: At the top of the caller class (`this` in the code provided) `public List<BattleshipPart> battleshipParts = new List<BattleshipPart>();`

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve] so we can see the full picture.

Comment: as the list is not cleared before the loop if that code runs twice you would have 2, or 3 or more depending on how many times it ran

Comment: @BugFinder Clearing the list worked, but not for the reason I would've thought. Surprisingly enough, `ScriptableObject.Awake` was invoked from assigning the reference to this object in the inspector. According to [Unity's docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.Awake.html) that should've only happened when the game runs.

Comment: A scriptable object retains its state variables until explicitly set.  It is easy to see this by adding a bool, press play and set it true, then hit stop in the editor.  The bool will stay true.  This is a bit different than monobehaviours, which may be the cause of confusion.

Comment: You're right, values stay remembered in the `.asset` files. However, I'm cloning the instance, and `Awake` shouldn't have been called by the inspector. At least not according to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This error because you create Instance not Asset and trying to save it into list.

Just create .asset(ScriptableObject) file with AssetDatabase in project.

```
    for (byte i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        BattleshipPart battleshipPart = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<BattleshipPart>();
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(battleshipPart, $"Assets/BattleshipPart_{i}.asset");
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();

        battleshipPart.battleshipData = this;
        battleshipParts.Add(battleshipPart);
    }
```

If you don't want to create asset file in your project, just use simple serialized class not ScriptableObject.